# AD SelfService for creating users

Tags: active-directory, user-management, credentials

I've set up a small computer lab with approx. 30 computers with Win8. They are connected to an Active Directory (Windows Server 2012R2) and have roaming profiles. However, creating users causes headaches (there is a high fluctuation, i.e. new students are there every two weeks).

The idea was to create a "new"-user in the AD, if there is a new student, he/she should be login with this "new"-user and then there should be an "self-adding" application or website, where they can type in their credentials and create their profiles for themselves.

After searching I've found a lot of "self-service"-password-reset applications, but not for creating users. Is there an application for that purpose? Otherwise I would set up a .net page and write a small script for that.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is a tool called Adaxes. With its help you can create a [WebUI](http://www.adaxes.com/active-directory_web-interface.htm) that can give access to AD. So for your scenario you can just customize the WebUI to show a form with the parameters that need to be entered and after a student puts his/her data in, the account is automatically created.

The nice thing about Adaxes is that you can put really a lot into it, e.g. you can generate missing parameters, create Exchange mailboxes, move to OUs, add to groups, delegate permissions with a RBAC system, assign Office 365 licences, etc. — all that automatically with no intervention on your behalf. However if you want to retain control, you can add an approval step, so nothing will happen until you hit the confirm button. Here's more detailed info: http://www.adaxes.com/active-directory_provisioning.htm

So it seems like Adaxes solves your problem completely in the exact way you were asking for. The only consideration point might be the price, but, obviously, it's up to you to decide.